# Error in fetching data from table into oracle apex form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create an edit profile page. However, when i try to populate the form with the info of the current user that is logged in, it tells me that there is an invalid number error. ‘Hiding error additional_info, as it contains ORA error message: ORA-01722: invalid number’

I have added this before header process where it will execute the plsql code

```
select user_id, fname, lname, email
into :P15_USER_ID, :P15_FNAME, :P15_LNAME, :P15_EMAIL
FROM user
where user_id = :APP_USER;
```

have tried numerous ways for eg i changed the app_user to v('APP_USER') but the same error message keeps coming back. Does anyone have any idea why? Alternatively, if there is any edit user profile page references that you may know of please let me know too, much appreciated for the help!

Comment: First thing to try... run the page in debug mode and check what sql statement or pl/sql block is throwing the exception. That will give you a hint in what direction to search. Most probably the issue is what @Justin Cave is saying but the information you have provided is very limited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of `:APP_USER` and what is the data type of `user_id`?  `:APP_USER` would normally be a username (i.e. 'jcave').  `user_id` would appear to be a numerical ID value (i.e. 12345).  Comparing the two does not appear to make sense.

In my example, Oracle would try to convert the string `jcave` to a number in order to compare against the numeric `user_id`.  That conversion would fail, throwing the error stack you're seeing.

Comment: I definitely overlooked this part, thank you! I now have a new error saying that no data is found. Am unsure why as a row was returned when i run the query in sql command.

Comment: @rkive - As suggested, debug the page.  I'd expect that the query you're running at the command line is different.  Perhaps there is a difference in the casing of `APP_USER` and the value you are searching on in your query for example.